# Force python blaze to use index

Tags: python, sql, indexing, blaze

I need to write something like this using blaze:

```
SELECT k2.field1
          , COUNT(1)
          FROM dbo.kp AS k1 WITH(INDEX(INDEX_kp_index1))
INNER JOIN dbo.kp AS k2 WITH(INDEX(INDEX_kp_index1)) ON k1.field2 = k2.field2
WHERE k1.field1 = '70675'
GROUP BY k2.field1
```

I need to specify the index, otherwise the query evaluates a very long time. Is there a way, how to do it? The table has multiple indexes.